# How can I create an apk of a VS 2010 project/solution using MonoDevelop?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin

Can anyone please tell me how to create an apk of a VS 2010 project or solution using MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 0):

Go to build and select Package  for Android. The .apk file will be in either your bin Debug or bin Release folder depending on your configuration manager settings.

You will not be able to deploy a working apk with the monoDroid trial version though.